# Why the io/invertase/firebase library use the external storage?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, android-external-storage

Our Cybersecurity team have reported that in our app the io/invertase/firebase library is using the external storage of the phone. The file reported is this:

[ReactNativeFirebaseUtilsModule.java](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/main/packages/app/android/src/reactnative/java/io/invertase/firebase/utils/ReactNativeFirebaseUtilsModule.java)

Please, somebody knows why the external storage is mentioned into that file?
I don't see a permission request from this library to access there, but in that case, Why it mention external storage into that file? I couln't follow the code to understand it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may help to read: https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html

Comment: Thanks, very interesting and useful post! Regarding that I see in the code I pasted above that Firebase is using, it map into a variable the Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory result, so as that is the "centralized places to store well-known file types, like photos and movies" it looks as they access there. I don't understand what they do there after that. Probably something related with Google Play Services, but it's not clear for me.

Comment: This answer was useful to me:
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/discussions/5975